# Trouble quering a join in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Theres a question on an exercise which asks me to write an SQL statement to show the SKU, SKU_Description, WarehouseID for all items stored in a warehouse managed by ‘Lucille Smith’. I have to use a join, but not use the JOIN ON syntax.

I came up with:

```
   select sku, sku_description, warehouseid 
   from inventory join warehouse
   inventory.warehouseid = warehouse.warehouseid
   where manager = 'lucille smith';
```

with the following errors

Error starting at line : 3 in command -

```
select Sku,SKU_DESCRIPTION,WAREHOUSEID 
from inventory join warehouse on
inventory.WAREHOUSEID = warehouse.warehouseid
      where manager = 'lucille smith'
```

Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 28
Error report -

`SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:
*Action:`

if it helps i added pictures of the tables warehouse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSsyd.png
inventory: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTa7w.png

Comment: If your join columns match up between the two joined tables, you should be ok with "from inventory join warehouse"

Comment: The statement you show above is syntactically incorrect, and wouldn't produce the error you show.  The error you show indicates that the statement does in fact use JOIN..ON which is what you say you can't use.  The error you're getting is simply that you need to qualify WAREHOUSEID in the select list with a table name, since it could come from either table.  But that doesn't seem to be your real question.

Comment: If your condition is `manager = 'lucille smith'` (all lower-case) and the actual string value is 'Lucille Smith' (as is shown in your picture), then you'll never get any rows.  String comparison is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the string comparison case sensitivity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the JOIN..USING syntax, as below:

**EDIT**:
Changed the manager name to Title Case

```
   select sku, sku_description, warehouseid 
   from inventory i join warehouse w
   using (warehouseid)
   where manager = 'Lucille Smith';
```

**Reference**:

[JOINS IN ORACLE on DATAWAREHOUSE CONCEPTS blog](http://dwhlaureate.blogspot.in/2012/08/joins-in-oracle.html)

Comment: I have tried the using syntax but it does not return anything. I added the pictures of the tables to clarify what it is I'm trying to do

Comment: I changed the name of the manager to title case as 'Lucille Smith'. No data was returned because the query contained the name in lowercase, whereas the data has it in title case.

Answer (score 1):

ORA-00918 tells you that ORACLE can't decide what column to select because both tables have columns with the same name.

To address that you need to use aliases like this:

```
select alias1.common_column, alias2.common_column
select table1 alias1, table2 alias2
```

If you are not allowed to use JOIN ON, you maybe can get away with old style syntax where all joining is done in WHERE clause.

Comment: You don't "need to use aliases".  You need to qualify the column name.  That could just as easily be done without aliases: `select table1.common_column, table2.common_column from table1, table2`

Answer (score 0):

You should use table aliases for all the columns.  Here is a guess as to what they are:

```
   select i.sku, i.sku_description, w.warehouseid 
   from inventory i join
        warehouse w
        on i.warehouse = w.warehouseid
   where w.manager = 'lucille smith';
```

The specific problem is probably caused by `warehouseid` in the `select`.  It could be from either table.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the join on syntax for this exercise.

Comment: I will try with table aliases

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to join tables without using JOIN..ON, then there are two possible answers:

1) use JOIN..USING as indicated in Joseph B's answer

2) use "old" Oracle syntax.  List the tables to be joined as a comma-separated list in the FROM clause, and put the join conditions in the WHERE clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t2.column2
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.join_column = t2.join_column
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this:-

```
SELECT I.sku, I.sku_description, W.warehouseid 
FROM INVENTORY I, WAREHOUSE W
WHERE I.warehouse = W.warehouseid
AND W.manager = 'lucille smith';
```

Hope this will help you and it is your's desired answer.....